# how to create this type of navbar in HTML

Tags: css, border, navbar

i tried creating this type of navbar using border-img but could not make it.
can anyone provide some help or code for it.[image]

Comment: Are you talking about the yellow menu item/menu? Next to MEA-CUPPA?

Comment: You'll need to provide some HTML and CSS, what you've tried, and what's not working. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @JuanTheron the slanted bottom border of navbar

Comment: That small yellow piece?

Comment: Oh one more thing, you already have an example, so just debug that site and see how they did it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I think I understand what you mean now.

I think you should have 2 options available to do the slanted bottom-border.

1. Use an image.  So the entire top header of the example site is an image then.

That includes the black part and the white bottom on an angle with the facebook banner.  This image is going to have to be png as it's gonna need an alpha layer.  PNG images are usually relatively large in filesize which makes it less attractive, but much simpler to implement.

2. Do it all with CSS:

```css
            html {
              height:100%;
            }
            body {
             height:100%;
             margin:0;padding:0;
            }
            h1,h2,p {
              color:white;
            }
            #header {
              /* Just the top banner */
              background-color:black;
              height:125px;
              text-align:left;
              padding-left:30px;
              color:white;
              font-size:50px;
              line-height:100px;
              -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 75px, 0% 100%);
              clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 75px, 0% 100%);
            }
            #content {
              position:relative;
              top:-50px;
              height:calc(100% - 125px - 25px);
              min-height:350px;
              background:url(http://files.all-free-download.com//downloadfiles/wallpapers/1920_1080/dark_forest_wallpaper_landscape_nature_1138.jpg);
              background-attachment:fixed;
              background-sizing:100% 100%;
              padding:75px 75px 0 75px;
              -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 70px, 100% 20px, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
              clip-path: polygon(0 70px, 100% 20px, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
            }
            .section {
              background-color:black;
              margin-top:-71px;
              padding:75px 75px 25px 75px;
              font-family:sans-serif;
            }
            .section > p {
              font-size:15px;
              padding:25px;
            }
```

```html
    <html>
            <head>
            </head>
            <body>
               <div id='header'>
                  TEST
               </div>
              <div id='content'>
                <h1>Title H1</h1>
                <h2>TITLE H2</h2>
                <p>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</p>
              </div>
              <div class='section'>
                <h1>SUPERCONDUCTIVITY</h1>
                <p>
                  Superconductivity is a phenomenon of exactly zero electrical resistance and expulsion of magnetic flux fields occurring in certain materials, called superconductors, when cooled below a characteristic critical temperature. It was discovered by Dutch physicist Heike Kamerlingh Onnes on April 8, 1911, in Leiden. Like ferromagnetism and atomic spectral lines, superconductivity is a quantum mechanical phenomenon. It is characterized by the Meissner effect, the complete ejection of magnetic field lines from the interior of the superconductor as it transitions into the superconducting state. The occurrence of the Meissner effect indicates that superconductivity cannot be understood simply as the idealization of perfect conductivity in classical physics.
             
                <br>
                <br>
              
The electrical resistance of a metallic conductor decreases gradually as temperature is lowered. In ordinary conductors, such as copper or silver, this decrease is limited by impurities and other defects. Even near absolute zero, a real sample of a normal conductor shows some resistance. In a superconductor, the resistance drops abruptly to zero when the material is cooled below its critical temperature. An electric current through a loop of superconducting wire can persist indefinitely with no power source.
            
                <br>
                <br>
             
In 1986, it was discovered that some cuprate-perovskite ceramic materials have a critical temperature above 90 K (−183 °C). Such a high transition temperature is theoretically impossible for a conventional superconductor, leading the materials to be termed high-temperature superconductors. The cheaply-available coolant liquid nitrogen boils at 77 K, and thus superconduction at higher temperatures than this facilitates many experiments and applications that are less practical at lower temperatures.
                </p>
              </div>
            </body>
            </html>
```

PS: I learned this while answering question here on StackOverflow, so this is news to me too.

Works like a charm!!